# Is there an excel function which returns an error if a cell is blank, and does nothing if it isn't

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I sometimes want a function that returns some value if the result is blank, and the result itself function otherwise.

Obviously `=IF(FUNCTION()="","WAS BLANK",FUNCTION())` works, but I hate the duplication.

With functions returning numbers I came up with a hacky solution using iferror

`=IFERROR(1/(1/FUNCTION()),"WAS ZERO")`

This is really useful to me, but I'm wondering if there's something similar I can do for functions which return text.

I do this to avoid UDFs/helper columns/duplication

Comment: I already have an IFBLANK udf but it's nice to have an option without haveing to resort to that

Comment: With your edit the only answer is `No it is not possible with native functions, without the duplication and/or a helper column`

Comment: @ScottCraner Re-reading the question, I agree. Sounds like you've got an answer.

Comment: What possible entries can FUNCTION() return? Without knowing, it's difficult to give a definite answer, though the fact that CODE returns an error when passed a null string ("") might lead you to try =IFERROR(CODE(FUNCTION()),"WAS BLANK").

Comment: @XORLX  That is a great tip, thanks. The specific application I was thinking of hear had a text lookup involved (so function would return a variable length string), but I have absolutely had 1 character returning functions where I wanted to do something **unless** it was blank before, so this is really useful.

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a way to force an error - For example, is there a way to keep a blank cell from reverting to 0? If there is, we could always do something like =iferror(ForceError,ComplexFunction), or some variant thereof to make it work.